# OpenCV: Assertion failed " dst.data == widget->original_image->data.ptr in function 'cvImageWidgetSetImage' "

Tags: c++, opencv, highgui

***IMPORTANT:*** I fixed the problem. **Solution at the end.**

**What do I try to achieve?**
Display an image with OpenCV *cv::imshow* method. ([imshow Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-alpha/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563))

The image which is a 3x3 matrix is created like such:

```
Mat mask(3, 3, CV_32F, new float[9]{0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0});
```

To display the image I call `imshow("mask", mask);`

**What is my problem?**
Like I mentioned in the title there is an exception thrown while trying to display the image. Complete Error Message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  
OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) /home/mrlab/Libraries/opencv_source/modules/highgui
/src/window_gtk.cpp:146: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 
dst.data == widget->original_image->data.ptr in function 'cvImageWidgetSetImage'
```

Link to [window_gtk.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f5b212a9d46bd6bf04b7d05d3d64a3a4dc80214e/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp#L146)

**What did I already try?**

1. Looking for the error on the internet. Maybe someone else already encountered the same problem. **nope. nothing**
2. Changed the matrix to only contain positive floating point values (0 to 1) in case it has problems with negative input. Initialization: `Mat mask(3, 3, CV_32F, new float[9]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0});` **same error**
3. Calling the two methods in different locations in case there are changes made during my other code. **same error**
4. Writing small OpenCV program to just run these two lines. **same error**
5. Various combinations of the above mentioned ideas. **same error**
6. Displaying other images I read from memory instead of creating them myself. **worked perfectly fine**
7. Saving the image via `imwrite("mask.png", mask)` Looks like
   [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW9Yv.png). Pretty small I know. I scaled the values to be in range of 0 to 255 since that what png needs. **works perfectly fine**

**Complete code around my corrupted lines:**

```
void high_pass(){

  Mat src_f;
  // Fourier transform src_bw
  src_f = fourier(src_bw);

  // Create Laplace High Pass Kernel
  Mat mask(3, 3, CV_32F, new float[9]{0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0});
  // In case of using fp values (0 to 1) initialize like this:
  // Mat mask(3, 3, CV_32F, new float[9]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0});
  imshow("mask", mask);

  // Fourier transform kernel
  Mat mask_f = fourier_kernel(mask, src_f.size());

  Mat hp_filtered;
  // Apply filter
  mulSpectrums(src_f, mask_f, hp_filtered, DFT_ROWS);

  // Transform it back
  dst = fourier_inv(hp_filtered);

  // Swap quadrants after applying filter
  dst = swap_quadrants(dst);

  // Show result
  //imshow(WINDOW_NAME + "high pass", dst);
}
```

**FYI:** The last line threw the same exception which is why it is commented out. I ask the question with "mask" because it is easier.

After writing the question I had another idea.

**Solution:** I converted the `CV_32F` type matrix to a `CV_8U` matrix and scaled all values to be in range of 0 to 255. This solved the problem.

This is something I should have thought of first. For some reason it took me one hour to realize. Just in case someone else is encountering the same error or mental block I still post this here.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Fixed it by reverting to the latest released version of OpenCV (3.4.3).

Comment: Ok. Good to know. I should have mentioned that I use OpenCV Version 4.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** I converted the CV_32F type matrix to a CV_8U matrix and scaled all values to be in range of 0 to 255. This solved the problem.

**Edit:** As stated by Nikolaj Fogh it is also possible to revert to OpenCV Version 3.4.3. I did not test it myself.

Comment: I was reaching the same conclusion about the variable type after printing out the type of the variable which couldn't be shows (`cout << dst.type();` gives type = 21, CV_32F), you found the solution, +1 and +1!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this is how to implement Philipp's solution (using his program's variables):

```
cv::Mat dist_8U; // to store the scaled image with appropriate type
double Min,Max;
cv::minMaxLoc(rgb,&Min,&Max);
dist -= Min;
dist.convertTo(dist_8U,CV_8U,255.0/(Max-Min));
```

Then `dist_8U` can be shown with `imshow` in opencv 4.0.0.
Tested on a raspberry pi.